# How to read a set of strings from terminal in Ubuntu and insert that values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, c, string, ubuntu

I would like to know how to read a set of strings sent to me and store the values in MySQL through terminal. The code i have to write is in C could someone share a sample code of how this can be achieved.

Comment: Need some more details like how you will be receiving strings? Is it through socket? Or through command line? Will the program be constantly awaiting for string inputs?

Answer (score 0):

This is not such a simple task. you have to read the data in C somehow, you should read more about [sockets](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/c-socket-programming/) this will give you an idea of how to get the data.

after you get the data you should store it in [mysql](http://www.mysql.com/), you should read their manual and install a **C connector** to connect it to C.

After you figure out how to connect C to mysql you can start running [queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/entering-queries.html)